# stuck at glowing boot logo during first installation

Tags: system-installation, release-juno, usb-drive

I am new to the Linux world so please bear with me if I don't know anything common.

That being said I tried to install elementary OS Juno [releas-juno](/questions/tagged/releas-juno) yesterday and when I booted from my flash drive it stuck at the glowing boot logo. I pressed <kbd>ESC</kbd> and it said `failed to start light display manager`. If its relevant I already have Windows installed and wanted to dual boot it.

Any solutions?

---

### Edit 1

I also have `failed to start network manager` and `failed to start detect available gpus` and deal with any system changes

---

### Edit 2

**Solved it**

The problem was in the flash drive. Used a new one and it worked like a charm. So if any one faced this problem try to change the boot device or use a dvd. It might work.

Comment: Closing as the author answered the question with an edit.